# How to give Exclusive edit permissions?

Tags: baseline, ibm-doors

a few days ago i developed a script in dxl to make a "first release" Baseline for each module in a project folder. But when I run the script appears a message saying I have not permissions to do so. This is my code:

```
void CreateBaseline (Module mod) {                     // Function to create
    create (mod, nextMajor(), "First Release")         //    baseline
}
Folder fStart = folder "/Z_Training/Baselines"         // Folder
Module iCurrent                                        // Module handler

for iCurrent in fStart do{           
setExclusive()                                         // Set Exclusive edit
Module (iCurrent, true)                                //    rights
CreateBaseline(iCurrent)
}
```

As you can see I included the line "setExclusive()" to deal with it, but this does not fix the problem completely since the baseline is created only for the current open Module. Could you help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The error message before adding the "setExclusive" function is this        -R-E- DXL: <Line:2> The user 'bryan.espinoza' has insufficient access
rights for this operation.
Backtrace:
 <Line:9> 
-I- DXL: execution halted

Comment: After adding setExclusive, the dlx edit window closes automatically and the pop up message "The DXL program has been modified closing the window will lose those changes" appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I omitted a step when answering [Is it possible to create a baseline for each module in a Folder using a dxl script (DOORS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420649/is-it-possible-to-create-a-baseline-for-each-module-in-a-folder-using-a-dxl-scri). Sorry, I do not have a DOORS installation at my current computer.

The method how to open a module in exclusive mode is described in the DXL manual, section "Module manipulation". You will need the perm `Module edit(string name
 [,bool disp[, bool silent[, bool loadStandardView]]])` (see the manual for a description of the parameters).

In this example this would be

```
[…] do {
Module mod = edit (fullName iCurrent, false, true, true)
CreateBaseline(mod)
```